# Unity3D spawning objects a certain distance away

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

Ok, so this question is kinda weird but I'll give it a shot. I have 4 lanes in my unity game that enemies travel on. All lanes lead to the same spot (the player). I have a variable that contains the distance squared between the enemy and the player. Now I want when I hit a special kind of enemy to move him to another lane. How do I use the distance variable I have to change its transform. Note: the lanes are just straight lines from 4 game objects to the player. I'm thinking of placing the teleporting enemy at the beginning of the lane and using `Vector3.MoveTowards`, but I can't work out the math.

Posting the whole code would not help, but here is the important bits

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _destination.position, Time.deltaTime * _speed);
distancesquared = (_destination.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
```

this moves the enemy in an Update() method and calculates the distance.

Now the enemies themselves are instantiated at random from an array of 4 transforms. When I want to teleport an enemy to another lane the first thing I do make its transform equal the spawn transform for that lane. Then I want to move it the same distance down the new lane that it has already travelled on the old one. 
Diagram of the lanes (sorry for bad paint skills)
[image]
Imagine that the lanes are the same length.

Comment: Could you post the code you've already got please, also a diagram might be useful.

Comment: @Adam H edited some code in. The bit of code I added is the one that moves the enemy , I dont see how the other code is connected to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by getting a unit direction vector for your line and then multiplying it by the distance that you want the creep to be along the line. Let's say that the transform for the lane you want to move to is called `toLane`, the enemy you want to move is called `enemy`, and the point where the creeps are moving towards (the player) is called `player`. The code would look something like this:

```
Vector3 direction = (toLane.transform.position - player.transform.position).normalized;
Vector3 distance = Vector3.Distance(enemy.transform.position, player.transform.position);
enemy.transform.position = direction * distance
```

This code will move the enemy to the position on the other lane at the distance from the player that it was before. You can then use your usual movement logic to move it in the right direction form then on (presumably you just need to tell it that it has moved lane).

Comment: Thank you for the help.
Sadly I cant seem to get your code to work for me . I ended up with this that just moves the creep down from its current lane.
`float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pathedEnemy._destination.position);
            Vector3 direction = (transform.position - pathedEnemy._destination.position).normalized;
            transform.position = testTransform.position;
            transform.position = direction * distance;
            Debug.Log("bla");`

Comment: I think it might just be a case of using the wrong transforms, I've updated my answer to include some terminology which should make it easier for you to use the code.

Comment: Thank you . You are my hero :D. Now it all makes sense. Thanks again.